# HTML + Button with text and image on it

Tags: php, html

I have a problem in creating a Button with text and image on it.

```
<td> 

<button type="submit" name="report" value="Report"  
<?php 
 if($tab == 'Excel') 
   echo "id=\"tab_inactive\""; 
 else 
   echo "id=\"tab_active\"" ; ?>>
 <img src="images/report.gif" alt="Report"/>Report
</button>

<button type="submit" name="excel" value="Excel"  
<?php 
 if($tab == 'Excel' )
     echo "id=\"tab_active\""; 
 else 
     echo "id=\"tab_inactive\"" ; ?>>
<img src="images/Excel.gif" alt="Excel" width="16" height="16" /> Excel
</button>

</td>
```

Here $tab is

```
$tab = strlen(trim($_POST[excel]))>0 ? $_POST[excel] : $_POST[report];
```

I tried this way, but this is behaving so strangely.
On click the button:- The submit function is working properly in firefox, but not in IE.

Instead of submitting the value(in this example values are 'Report' and 'Excel'), indeed it is submitting the label of the button.

That is if i am checking the value of array PRINT_R($_POST). The value of it is

```
Array ( [report] =>(Icon that i used) Report 
        [excel] => (Icon that i used) Excel 
        [frm_analysis] => [to_analysis] => )
```

Here i have more than 1 button, then all the labels are submitted eventhough one of them is pressed.  i dont how to capture which button is pressed.

I even tried changing `button type=button and onclick="document.formname.submit()"` Even this is resulting in the same.

Can you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>`s are broken in IE. I think they corrected it in IE7 or 8. Is the page in standards mode? That may help in IE7 or 8.

If you need to support the broken version, you could try and work around it with JS, if you don't mind being dependent on it. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function buttonclicked(button) {
    button.form.elements["buttonclicked"].value = this.value;
  }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="buttonclicked" value="">
<button type="submit" name="report" onclick="buttonclicked(this)">
 <img src="images/report.gif" alt="Report"/>Report
</button>
<button type="submit" name="excel" onclick="buttonclicked(this)">
<img src="images/Excel.gif" alt="Excel" width="16" height="16" /> Excel
</button>
```

I don't think there is any other way other than avoiding `<button>` and using `<input  type=submit>` if you need to distinguish between which on was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This, unfortunately, is IE's default behaviour when dealing with `<button>` elements. There is, to my knowledge, no real solution to this problem, although there are ofcourse numerous workarounds.

My suggestion would be as follows:

Create a radio button control called `report_type` (or whatever you choose), with two radio buttons: One for Excel and one for Report. Also, include a regular submit button.

With Javascript (if it's enabled), you can hide the radio buttons and submit button (`display: none`), and create (through JS) two buttons, labeled Report and Excel. On clicking one of these buttons, the proper radio button is checked, and the form is submitted.

This will allow you to create the form in it's current form, while providing a working fallback for users without javascript support.

And instead of the button's value, you can now look at the Radio's value to decide which form of reporting you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button title="Search" onClick="javascript:executeFunction();">Search<br /><img src="images/search_icon.gif"/><br />More Text</button>
```

Comment: Thanku for the quick reply. Here onclick, i want to submit the form. so if i write onclick=document.Formname.submit();. How will i come to know which button is pressed. Do i need to handle that button value through hidden text fields in my javascript or any other alternative?

Comment: Personally I'd use executeFunction(this), and let the executeFunction() set a hidden field to identify which button has been clicked (identified by this) before doing the actual submission from within the function

Answer (score 0):

since your image is included within the `<button> (<input>?)` tag, it is likely being included in the value.

Why not use an img with either an onclick event or a href with a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it, just one idea:

```
<td> 

<button type="submit" name="active_page" value="Report"  
<?php 
 if( isset( $_POST['active_page'] ) && $_POST['active_page'] == 'Excel' ) 
   echo "id=\"tab_inactive\""; 
 else 
   echo "id=\"tab_active\"" ; ?>>
 <img src="images/report.gif" alt="Report"/>Report
</button>

<button type="submit" name="active_page" value="Excel"  
<?php 
 if( isset( $_POST['active_page'] ) && $_POST['active_page'] == 'Excel' )
     echo "id=\"tab_active\""; 
 else 
     echo "id=\"tab_inactive\"" ; ?>>
<img src="images/Excel.gif" alt="Excel" width="16" height="16" /> Excel
</button>

</td>
```

Dont really understand your problem, is it this:

You want to now wich Button was clicked, to show the tab or and other tab? Right?